# Mathematics behind the function "approx3d"

Tags: interpolation, approximation

Can someone provide me reference regarding the mathematics of the "approx3d" function? Does this function apply "trilinear interpolation"?

Comment: Is `approx3d` part of some common library like [`Numpy`](https://www.numpy.org/) or [`Scipy`](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html)? The answer is likely specific to an implementation.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't my question correct?

Comment: @AndrewF This function is form "oce".

Comment: @David And what is "oce"?

Comment: @melpomene It's the corresponding library.

Answer (score 0):

The only `approx3d` implementation I could find is a library in R, [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/oce/versions/1.0-1/topics/approx3d) and indeed it says it uses "trilinear approximation."

The simpler case would be "[bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)". Given two points on a plane, the interpolated middle-point is just the average of those two given points.

[Trilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) is similar, except that in three dimensions you must average three points (not two) and average their three coordinates. You may notice that if (for example) both points have the same X-coordinate (say x=0), then the problem reduces to bilinear interpolation again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I want to understand the mathematics behind this function. But I can't find relevant document.